# How do you properly wrap Google Calendar inside div and make it responsive?

Tags: html, css, google-calendar-api

I'm working on the right section of a website where it has a slide of pictures running at the top, and right below it I wanted to embed a Google Calendar. I noticed that the Google Calendar isn't responsive, and I found a way to make it responsive, however I am having trouble making the Google Calendar responsive AND making it stay within it's div.

Through trial and error I found that I get to either make the Google Calendar responsive or aligned in it's div, not both.

And just to note, I'm not sure if this makes any different, but from the tutorial I followed in order to make the Google Calendar responsive, the iframe ***needs*** to be wrapped by a div class. I tried messing around and tried with div id, and the calendar stopped being responsive.

[Google Calendar being responsive but not properly aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4Eet.png)

[Google Calendar properly aligned but not responsive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoeXK.png)

I am assuming the problem is because of how the code is currently set up. Could someone explain if it's okay if I put div inside an article element?

Here is the HTML:

```
  <!-- Right Section -->
<div class="col span_2_of_3">


    <!-- Events -->
    <article class="events">
        <h2>UPCOMING EVENTS</h2>
        <div id="slider">
            <figure>
                <a href="http://wrrc.ucdavis.edu/community.html"><img src="../images/vstories.jpg" alt=""></a>
                <a href="http://wrrc.ucdavis.edu/community.html"><img src="../images/WeeklyEvents-01.jpg" alt=""></a>
                <a href="http://wrrc.ucdavis.edu/community.html"><img src="../images/STEM4GIRLS.jpg" alt=""></a>
                <a href="http://wrrc.ucdavis.edu/community.html"><img src="../images/slide00.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </figure>
        </div>
        <!-- <button>VIEW CALENDAR</button> -->
    </article>


    <!-- Google Calendar -->
    <article class="calendar">
        <div class="responsive-iframe-container">
            <iframe src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?height=600&amp;wkst=1&amp;bgcolor=%23ffffff&amp;src=wrrcdavis%40gmail.com&amp;color=%2323164E&amp;ctz=America%2FLos_Angeles" style="border-width:0" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" position="relative"></iframe>
        </div>
    </article>

</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
  /*Columns*/
.col {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    margin: 1% 0 1% 2%;
}
.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; }


/*  GROUPING  */
.group:before,
.group:after { content:""; display:table; }
.group:after { clear:both;}
.group { zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */ }

/*  GRID OF THREE  */
.span_2_of_3 { 
    width: 66%;
    min-height: 500px;
    height:auto;  }
.span_1_of_3 { 
    width: 32%;
    min-height: 500px;
    height:auto; }


/*  GO FULL WIDTH BELOW 480 PIXELS */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .col {  margin: 1% 0 1% 0%; }
    .span_2_of_3, .span_1_of_3 { width: 100%; }
}

/* Calendar */ 
.calendar{
border-top: none;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    padding-left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    }


/* Responsive iFrame */

.responsive-iframe-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 30px;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}


.responsive-iframe-container iframe,   
.vresponsive-iframe-container object,  
.vresponsive-iframe-container embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also go for two div's, each with a different view:

I used the "month" calendar embed option for the big container:

```
<div class="responsive-iframe-container big-container">
    <iframe src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?showTitle=0&amp;showNav=0&amp;showPrint=0&amp;showTabs=0&amp;showCalendars=0&amp;showTz=0&amp;height=700&amp;wkst=1&amp;bgcolor=%23ffffff&amp;src=(your_src)&amp;color=%232952A3&amp;ctz=America%2FNew_York" style="border-width:0" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
```

Then used the "agenda" calendar embed option for mobile devices:

```
<div class="responsive-iframe-container small-container">
    <iframe src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?showTitle=0&amp;showNav=0&amp;showPrint=0&amp;showTabs=0&amp;showCalendars=0&amp;showTz=0&amp;mode=AGENDA&amp;height=800&amp;wkst=1&amp;bgcolor=%23ffffff&amp;src=(your_src)&amp;color=%232952A3&amp;ctz=America%2FNew_York&amp;mode=AGENDA" style="border-width:0" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
```

Throw in the css at the top of the page to do it's magic:

```
<style>
 @media (max-width: 550px) {
     .big-container {display: none;}
 }
 @media (min-width: 550px) {
     .small-container {display: none;}
 }
 /* Responsive iFrame */
 .responsive-iframe-container {
     position: relative;
     padding-bottom: 56.25%;
     padding-top: 30px;
     height: 0;
     overflow: hidden;
 }
 .responsive-iframe-container iframe,   
 .vresponsive-iframe-container object,  
 .vresponsive-iframe-container embed {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
 }
 </style>
```

When I first tested it, they both appeared when I resized my page.. not sure why. Upon another refresh it worked like a charm. So give it a try!
([Original source](https://answers.squarespace.com/questions/54774/how-to-embed-a-google-calendar-in-a-responsive-way.html))

Answer (score 0):

For anybody else that comes across this question, here is a simplified (and slightly altered) version of Malachi's answer that makes it a little easier to understand what's happening. In this version, I changed the aspect ratio of the calendar widget when the browser width is less/greater than 550 px using the `padding-bottom` property with the CSS `@media` rule.

```html
<style>
/* CSS for responsive iFrame for calendar*/
@media (min-width: 550px) {
  .responsive-iframe-container {padding-bottom: 75%;}
}
@media (max-width: 550px) {
  .responsive-iframe-container {padding-bottom: 150%;}
}
.responsive-iframe-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 0;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.responsive-iframe-container iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
</style>

<div class="responsive-iframe-container">
  <iframe src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?height=600&amp;wkst=1&amp;bgcolor=%23ffffff&amp;src=wrrcdavis%40gmail.com&amp;color=%2323164E&amp;ctz=America%2FLos_Angeles" style="border-width:0" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" position="relative"></iframe>
</div>
```